# $p^{th}$ power residue symbol for $p$-free numbers that are coprime to $p$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Recall that if a number field $K$ contains the primitive $p^{th}$ root of unity $\zeta_{p}$, then for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$ coprime to $p$ and every $\mathfrak{p}$-adic unit $\alpha$ of $K$, $\big( \frac{\alpha}{\mathfrak{p}}\big)_{p}$ is the unique number $\zeta_{p}^{j}$ that satisfies the congruence
$$\alpha^{\frac{N\mathfrak{p}-1}{p}} \equiv \zeta_{p}^{j} (\text{mod } \mathfrak{p}),$$ where N$\mathfrak{p}$ is the absolute norm of $\mathfrak{p}$.

Notation: I will be using that a number $a$ is $p$-free if $a$ is not divisible by $p^{th}$ power of any prime.

For $p=2$, this gives us Legendre symbol : we know that for a square-free integer $a$ such that $p \nmid a$ $\big(\frac{a}{p}\big)_{2} = +1$ if and only if $a$ is a square modulo $p$. In fact, this is true for any $a$ coprime to $p$.

Let $q \neq p$ be an integer prime. Is it true that for a $p$-free number $a$ coprime to $q$, $(\frac{a}{q}\big)_{p} = +1$ if and only if $a$ is a $p^{th}$ power modulo $q$? Since the group of $p^{th}$ power residue is the group of $p^{th}$ root of unity, we have more than two elements in the group of $p^{th}$ power residue symbol. Therefore, I cannot really seem to figure out an answer, one way or the another.

Comment: Is $(\frac{a}{p}\big)_{p}$ a typo? $(\frac{a}{\mathfrak{p}}\big)_{p}=1$ iff the order of $a\bmod \mathfrak{p}$ divides $(N\mathfrak{p}-1)/p$, and $O_K/\mathfrak{p}^\times$ being cyclic it is iff $\exists b, a=b^p \bmod \mathfrak{p}$ (would be less confusing if renaming $p$ as $n$)

Comment: @reuns I think I have corrected it. I am looking to prove the statement for $p^{th}$ power, modulo primes $q \neq p$ And $a$ is just an ordinary $p$-free integer. Right now, I was only interested in prime powers. You are right though, earlier my notations were incorrect.

Comment: $q$ is a prime integer ? If $p |q-1$ then $a\bmod q$ is a $p$-th power iff $(a/\mathfrak{q})_p = 1$ for some prime $\mathfrak{q}$ above $q$ in $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$. If $p\nmid q-1$ then $O_K/\mathfrak{q}$ is automatically larger than $\Bbb{F}_q$ and $(a/\mathfrak{q})_p$ is about $p$-th powers in that larger finite field.